# ¿Es lo mismo "ser proactivo" que "tener iniciativa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

Una palabra que gusta mucho en entornos empresariales, por motivos obvios, es "proactivo". Hasta hace poco yo siempre me quejaba de que esa palabra no debía ser usada, puesto que no venía en el diccionario, y además en español tenemos la expresión "tener iniciativa", que venía a decir lo mismo.

Sin embargo, ya me he quedado sin argumentos, puesto que en la última edición del diccionario tenemos:

> **[proactivo, va](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UDj79Cj)**
>
> Del ingl. *proactive*, creado por oposición a *reactive* 'reactivo'.
>
> 1. adj. Psicol. Que toma activamente el control y decide qué hacer en cada momento, anticipándose a los acontecimientos. *Persona, empresa proactiva.* Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Psicol. Que implica acción o intervención activa.

Así pues, se ha acabado añadiendo el anglicismo al diccionario. Sin embargo, ahora me entra la duda de si yo realmente tenía razón al indicar que "una persona proactiva" y "una persona con iniciativa" son la misma cosa. ¿Es así, o existen diferencias entre ambas? Si no es así, ¿existía alguna otra alternativa en español a la palabra "proactivo"?

Comment: Yo diría que las definiciones de la palabra "proactivo" casan a la perfección con el significado de la expresión "tener iniciativa".

Answer (score 4):

Como ocurre con los sinónimos en general, siempre (o casi siempre) hay matices que hacen que las palabras o frases en cuestión no sean exactamente equivalentes.

En primer lugar, debemos decir  que "proactivo" como adjetivo es más equiparable a "con iniciativa": Una persona **proactiva** es una persona **con iniciativa**, o una persona **que tiene iniciativa.** (Nótese el uso de la frase preposicional y de la proposición relativa, ambas de valor adjetivo.)

Dicho esto, en mi opinión "proactivo" tiene mucho -- como bien dice la definición -- de adelantarse o anticiparse a los hechos. Una persona proactiva no espera que le den órdenes: observa la necesidad y pone manos a la obra sin esperar instrucciones. Alguien con iniciativa es, al igual que alguien proactivo, autónomo, pero su virtud radica más en la creatividad que en la anticipación. La diferencia -- si la hay -- es muy sutil.

Comment: Debo concluir entonces que mi afirmación de que "una persona proactiva es lo mismo que una con iniciativa" es correcta (salvo leves matices descartables), ¿no es así?

Comment: Sí, pero no descartaría lo de la anticipación. Además, el adjetivo "proactivo" es, como bien dices, más usado en el ámbito empresarial, porque define la personalidad del empleado. Además, al ser modificador directo es más versátil. Compara: "muy/sumamente proactivo" vs. "con mucha iniciativa", "bastante proactivo" vs. "con bastante iniciativa", "poco proactivo" vs. "con poca iniciativa".

Comment: (+1) the distinction made here is similar to the English one and since it is an anglicism perhaps that is relevant. The person taking the initiative is leading, the proactive person is acting in advance of some event or problem. Of course often that amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I fully agree. The one taking the initiative is not always proactive. Note, however, that "taking the initiative" is temporary or occasional. "being proactive" would be closer to "having initiative" as a permanent quality.